# Turning one row into multiple rows in r

Tags: r, multiple-columns, transpose

In R, I have data where each person has multiple session dates, and the scores on some tests, but this is all in one row. I would like to change it so I have multiple rows with the persons info, but only one of the session dates and corresponding test scores, and do this for every person. Also, each person may have completed different number of sessions.

Ex:

```
ID  Name  Session1Date  Score  Score  Session2Date  Score  Score
23  sjfd  20150904      2      3      20150908      5      7
28  addf  20150905      3      4      20150910      6      8
```

To:

```
ID  Name  SessionDate  Score  Score
23  sjfd  20150904     2      3     
23  sjfd  20150908     5      7
28  addf  20150905     3      4
28  addf  20150910     6      8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `melt` from the devel version of `data.table` ie. `v1.9.5`.  It can take multiple 'measure' columns as a list.  Instructions to install are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("Date$", "Score(\\.2)*$", "Score\\.[13]"))
#   ID Name variable   value1 value2 value3
#1: 23 sjfd        1 20150904      2      3
#2: 28 addf        1 20150905      3      4
#3: 23 sjfd        2 20150908      5      7
#4: 28 addf        2 20150910      6      8
```

Or using `reshape` from `base R`, we can specify the `direction` as 'long' and `varying` as a `list` of column index

```
 res <- reshape(df1, idvar=c('ID', 'Name'), varying=list(c(3,6), c(4,7), 
         c(5,8)), direction='long')
 res  
 #            ID Name time Session1Date Score Score.1
 #23.sjfd.1 23 sjfd    1     20150904     2       3
 #28.addf.1 28 addf    1     20150905     3       4
 #23.sjfd.2 23 sjfd    2     20150908     5       7
 #28.addf.2 28 addf    2     20150910     6       8
```

If needed, the `rownames` can be changed

```
 row.names(res) <- NULL
```

#### Update

If the columns follow a specific order i.e. 3rd grouped with 6th, 4th with 7th, 5th with 8th, we can create a `matrix` of column index and then `split` to get the `list` for the `varying` argument in `reshape`.

```
 m1 <- matrix(3:8,ncol=2)
 lst <- split(m1, row(m1))
 reshape(df1, idvar=c('ID', 'Name'), varying=lst, direction='long')
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without typing in all the variable names because I have 625 columns?

Comment: @Michael You can use `merged.stack` from `splitstackshape` but we need to have some patterns for the common column names or we need to know if the column follow a specific sequence

Comment: @Michael I updated a possible option if the columns are following a specific order as in the example.  We create a `list` after splitting the column index of the 'measure' columns created in a matrix.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm pretty new to R, but in your answer using reshape, what is varying=list specifying, I can't seem to figure out what those numbers correspond to?

Comment: @Michael `lst` is `list` of column index.  If you type `lst` on the R console, you will see that the first lst element is `lst[[1]]` corresponds to `3 6` ie, the columns we want to group together.  Likewise, we group `4 7` and `5 8` as they are separate list elements

Comment: @Michael In your original dataset, the column grouping may be different.  But, you can create the list similarly if you know which columns you need to group

Comment: @Swanny, see the updated solution. You can use regex in `melt` with the help of `patterns()` function.

Comment: @Arun the `patterns()` is new for me.  Great addition! (looks like I have reinstall the devel version :-)

Comment: Thanks! Added it recently. Looks cleaner 

Answer (score 0):

If your data frame name is `data`

Use this

```
data1 <- data[1:5]
data2 <- data[c(1,2,6,7,8)]
newdata <- rbind(data1,data2)
```

This works for the example you've given. You might have to change column names appropriately in data1 and data2 for a proper `rbind`