# R- How to put multiple cases (rows) in one row

Tags: r, transpose

I am doing some coding in R and have encountered an issue.

I have a data set where participants were given the same question(s) a few different times.    There is one id variable, a time variable which records which instance we are dealing with, and one outcome variable.

I did a little research and found a post similar to what I am trying to do.

[Turning one row into multiple rows in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896908/turning-one-row-into-multiple-rows-in-r)

I am trying to do the exact opposite thing of what is being done in this post.

I created this small code to give an idea of what I am dealing with.

```
A1
id       time  x
1000     1     1
1000     2     2
1000     3     3
1000     4     4
1001     1     1
1001     2     2
1001     3     3
1001     4     4
```

What I need to do is reorganize the data set so that each case is on one line and I repeat every X variable multiple times (x1 would be the first time point, x2 would be the second time point, etc).  Here is a sample code of what I would like the final data frame to look like.

```
B1
id     x1     x2     x3     x4
1000    1     2      3      4
1001    1     2      3      4
```

There are a few nuances in my code that make this situation really tricking.  Some participants have many more x entries than other participants (some participants only have 1 or 2 different x values while others have 7 or 8).  There is some missing data as well.

I have approached the problem in a few ways with no luck.  I am not sure what the best way is to handle this situation.  The attempts I have tried either require a lot of code, usually the same basic code repeating multiple times, or code that doesn't work.  Here is what I have tried.

I tried to use a for loop.  I tried to create a new variable to identify the participant by id and then identify the first time they are doing the survey, then I use the first x value.  I would then repeat this for each time point(for time 2- find the second x value for a given participant, for time 3- find the third x value for a given participant, etc.).  As I have currently anywhere from 1 to 10 time points, this involves a lot of  for loops.  Because some people don't have an 6 or 7th time, the code often doesn't run.  Here is an example of the for loop I have tried.

```
for (i in A1$id) {
  temp.txt<- paste (
    c ("A1$x1 [A$id ==", i," & A$time == 1] <- A1$x"
    ),   collapse = "")
  eval (parse(text = temp.txt))
}
```

I tried to subset the data for each time point, then merge the data together at the end.  If I try this, I have missing data, and I also encounter issues with variables names no longer being accepted (I think because the names are similar, R has an issue with renaming everything).  Here is an example of what that code looks like.

```
t1 <- subset (A1, A$time == 1)
t2 <- subset (A1, A$time == 2)
t3 <- subset (A1, A$time == 3)
t4 <- subset (A1, A$time == 4)

Z1 <- merge (t1, t2, by = "id")
Z2 <- merge (Z1, t3, by = "id")
Z3 <- merge (Z2, t4, by = "id")
```

Is there a different/easier way to approach this issue?  Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked perfectly.  In case anyone else has this issue, here  is the documentation on reshape ()  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/reshape

Comment: Can you provide a better example and the corresponding output. The one in the question is ambiguous since the x and time columns are the same so we can't really tell which is which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) reshape** This is referred to as converting long form to wide form.  In base R we can use `reshape` giving the following data frame.  Note that `reshape` assumes that if there are columns named `id` and `time` then those are the id and time columns but if they had been named something else we would have had to specify them using the appropriate `reshape` arguments.

```
reshape(DF, dir = "wide")
##     id x.1 x.2 x.3 x.4
## 1 1000   1   2   3   4
## 5 1001   1   2   3   4
```

**2) xtabs** Another base R solution is to use `xtabs` which gives the following table object:

```
xtabs(x ~ ., DF)
##       time
## id     1 2 3 4
##   1000 1 2 3 4
##   1001 1 2 3 4
```

**3) tapply** or `tapply` which gives this matrix:

```
with(DF, tapply(x, list(id, time), c))
##      1 2 3 4
## 1000 1 2 3 4
## 1001 1 2 3 4
```

**4) pivot wider** The tidyr package has `pivot_wider` to do this:

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(DF, names_from = "time", values_from = x)
## # A tibble: 2 x 5
##      id   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
##   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
## 1  1000     1     2     3     4
## 2  1001     1     2     3     4
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "id       time  x
1000     1     1
1000     2     2
1000     3     3
1000     4     4
1001     1     1
1001     2     2
1001     3     3
1001     4     4"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: That's really simple solution with `reshape`, upvoted!

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Reshape worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` you can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A1) #Converting into data.table
result <- dcast(A1, id~x, value.var= "time") #long to wide conversion
names(result)[-1]<- paste0("x.",names(result)[-1]) #setting the names accordingly
result #your result

     id x.1 x.2 x.3 x.4
1: 1000   1   2   3   4
2: 1001   1   2   3   4
```