# Break a dataframe which is spread across one row to multiple row with specific column

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, reshape

I have a data set which looks like this example

```
name  test marks   name.1  test.1  marks.1 name.2 test.2 marks.2  name.3 test.3   marks.3
Jon   math  456     Ria   history  564      Nia   math   456       Tom   physics  567
```

However, my original dataset is very wide with around 700 columns.
I wish to reshape this dataset which is spread across one row to multiple row in R

I want an output which should look like this

```
name test     marks
Jon  math     456
Ria  history  564
Nia  math     456
Tom  physics  567
```

I referred [Reshaping multiple sets of columns (wide format) into single columns (long format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1) , [Turning one row into multiple rows in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896908/turning-one-row-into-multiple-rows-in-r) and many more but unable to find a proper solution.

I will really appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `".value"` in `names_to` and supply one of `names_sep` or `names_pattern` to specify how the column names should be split.

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c(".value", NA), names_pattern = "([^.]+)\\.?(.*)")

# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#   name  test    marks
#   <chr> <chr>   <int>
# 1 Jon   math      456
# 2 Ria   history   564
# 3 Nia   math      456
# 4 Tom   physics   567
```

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(name = "Jon", test = "math", marks = 456L, name.1 = "Ria",
    test.1 = "history", marks.1 = 564L, name.2 = "Nia", test.2 = "math",
    marks.2 = 456L, name.3 = "Tom", test.3 = "physics", marks.3 = 567L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: Thanks @Darren Tsai, I tried the solution provided by you it is stacking all the values from second row for my dataset i.e It displaying a table with column `name` ,`test` ,`marks` with   1st row values and all other values as NA and stacking rest of the rows by creating another columns `name.` , `test.` and `marks.` Can you please suggest why this is happening? My dataset is exactly the example provided

Comment: I am sorry but I am very new to R, how to set regex for `names_pattern` ? Is there any way to make regex patten?